# Custom UITableViewCell does not display correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewCell to use in a TableView. The cell appears correctly in the storyboard but when I display it in the TableView it appears completely jumbled. I have looked at similar questions however their problems seem to have been naming of outlets and Xcode bugs. What am I missing?

UITableViewCell

```
class ArticleLargeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

public static let Identifier = "ArticleLargeTableViewCell"

@IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var favoriteButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var articleImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var articleType: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var articleTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var articleDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var articleSource: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var articleFavicon: UIImageView!
private var shareClickListener: (Article) -> Void = { _ in }
private var favoriteClickListener: (Article) -> Void = { _ in }
private var article: Article!

override class func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func setData(article: Article, shareClickListener: @escaping (Article) -> Void, favoriteClickListener: @escaping (Article) -> Void, shouldShowMoreButton: Bool = true) {
    self.article = article
    articleImage.sd_setImage(with: article.getImageUrl())
    articleImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    articleImage.clipsToBounds = true
    articleTitle.text = article.title
    let textColor = UIColor(named: "text")
    articleTitle.textColor = textColor
    articleSource.text = article.source.title
    articleSource.textColor = textColor
    articleDate.textColor = UIColor(named: "caption")
    articleDate.text = article.date.timeAgo()
    self.shareClickListener = shareClickListener
    self.favoriteClickListener = favoriteClickListener
    articleType.image = article.articleType().getTypeImage()
    articleFavicon.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: article.faviconUrl)!)
    favoriteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onFavoriteButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onShareButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func onShareButtonClick() {
    shareClickListener(article)
}

@objc func onFavoriteButtonClick() {
    favoriteClickListener(article)
}
}
```

ViewController

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Combine
import MaterialComponents.MaterialActionSheet

class ArticlesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var articlesList: UITableView!
    private var articles: [Article] = []
    var viewModel: ArticlesViewModel!
    private var useCompactView: Bool = true
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        articlesList.dataSource = self
        articlesList.delegate = self
        viewModel.$viewState.sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in}, receiveValue: { viewState in
            switch viewState {
            case .loading:
                print()
            case .error:
                print()
            case let .data(data):
                self.setData(data: data)
            }
        })
    }
    
    private func setData(data: ArticlesViewModel.ViewState.Data) {
        self.articles = data.articles
        self.title = data.title
        self.useCompactView = data.useCompactView
        if self.useCompactView {
            articlesList.register(UINib(nibName: ArticleUiTableViewCell.Identifier, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: ArticleUiTableViewCell.Identifier)
        } else {
            articlesList.register(UINib(nibName: ArticleLargeTableViewCell.Identifier, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: ArticleLargeTableViewCell.Identifier)
        }
        articlesList.reloadData()
        articlesList.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return articles.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if useCompactView {
            guard let cell = articlesList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ArticleUiTableViewCell.Identifier, for: indexPath) as? ArticleUiTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("could not cast to articles cell")
            }
            // display other cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = articlesList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ArticleLargeTableViewCell.Identifier, for: indexPath) as? ArticleLargeTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("could not cast to articles cell")
            }
            let article = articles[indexPath.item]
            cell.setData(article: article, shareClickListener: { article in
                self.shareLink(description: article.title, url: article.originalUrl)
            }, favoriteClickListener: { article in
                self.viewModel.favoriteArticle(article: article, delegate: UIApplication.shared.delegate)
            })
            return cell
        }
    }
 
}
```

AutoLayout
[image]

Output
[image]

I have tried returning an explicit height as you can see below, but I get a similar error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 467
}
```

Comment: check for the cell height

Comment: You're not showing the Height constraint for your large image... is it an explicit value, or a ratio? I'll assume you have something that is just not shown in your images. However, you're also not showing any constraints to the bottom of the content view, which may be the key issue. Add a constraint from the bottom of the Favorite button to the bottom of the content view and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The large image simply has a 18:9 aspect ratio. I have added a constraint bottom = Favorite.bottom +4 but still have this issue @DonMag

Comment: Are you setting the class of "Content View" of the "ArticleLargeTableViewCell" to some custom sub class of UIView? I faced similar problem when i do so, all sub view & label shrink to the left when I try to add an appearance to all of my UIView by adding a custom sub class.

Comment: @paky wow. that was it. I was setting it to an MDCard. Post your comment as an answer and Ill accept it. I'd also love if you included your workaround to the problem (How do i still wrap all my contents within an MDCard)

Comment: Glad to be of help :) answer posted and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the class of the content view of a UITableViewCell may result in unexpected behaviours, as the content view is the default superview of the content and UIKit might process some configuration on it. (which I can't find a clear instruction from the documentation)

[Reference from Apple's Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZATuy.png)

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content that the cell displays. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they position appropriately as the cell transitions in to and out of editing mode.

So a workaround of adding a custom subview, is to add it as a subview of the content view, and leave the content view's properties untouched. Then you can wrap all your content inside the your custom view.

[image: Avoid changing the class of content view]

Comment: You're misunderstanding that description. The cell itself is a **view**. The cell has a "built-in" view - the `contentView` - which is where Apple is saying to add subviews... which you have just done by adding `YourCustomView` to it. There is no difference.

Comment: Yes the cell has a "built-in" contentView, but when you override its class, things go messy as Adrain said. My solution is a workaround based on Adrain wants to use his custom class MDCard in autolayout.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't see the additional comment that the Adrian was changing the class of the cell's `contentView`. So, yes, you are correct... absolutely he should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

After seeing additional comments from the OP - that he was ***changing the class of the cell's `contentView` - this answer is moot (although it does produce a valid cell).

This highlights one of the reasons to include **complete** details when posting questions here.

---

**Original Answer**

It's a little tough to figure out, since you haven't shown all the constraints.

Here's an example that should get what you want (or, at least, get you where you need to be)...

The layout looks like this:

[image]

Note the class assignments:

[image]

[image]

To test this, here is example code:

```
class ArticleLargeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    public static let Identifier = "ArticleLargeTableViewCell"
    
    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var source: UILabel!

}

class ArticlesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var articlesList: UITableView!

    let myData: [String] = [
        "Source text for first row.",
        "Longer source text which should be enough to word-wrap when running on an iPhone.",
        "This source text\nhas embedded\nnewline characters\nto get four rows in the label."
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//      articlesList.register(UINib(nibName: ArticleUiTableViewCell.Identifier, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: ArticleUiTableViewCell.Identifier)
        articlesList.register(UINib(nibName: ArticleLargeTableViewCell.Identifier, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: ArticleLargeTableViewCell.Identifier)

        articlesList.dataSource = self
        articlesList.delegate = self
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ArticleLargeTableViewCell.Identifier, for: indexPath) as! ArticleLargeTableViewCell
        cell.title.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.source.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

and here's the source for `ArticleLargeTableViewCell.xib` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="402" id="9CN-96-cbN" customClass="ArticleLargeTableViewCell" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="402"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="9CN-96-cbN" id="hnF-dN-5dt">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="402"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Random Title" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4cS-dj-yG9">
                        <rect key="frame" x="60" y="8" width="108" height="21"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="6 minutes ago" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="FaY-ve-Qel">
                        <rect key="frame" x="60" y="29" width="109" height="21"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JO1-nS-Fg0">
                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="44" height="44"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="JO1-nS-Fg0" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="ozT-ci-zDr"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="44" id="z0X-tH-CKE"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </imageView>
                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tub-UY-Qc6">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="129" width="414" height="207"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="tub-UY-Qc6" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="18:9" id="Kyi-bC-PWn"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </imageView>
                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bBl-zC-cYt">
                        <rect key="frame" x="386" y="8" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.47843137250000001" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="bBl-zC-cYt" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="68L-BJ-oE4"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="20" id="qde-Gw-mBE"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </imageView>
                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aLg-Yr-ndG">
                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="344" width="55" height="30"/>
                        <state key="normal" title="Favorite"/>
                    </button>
                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Vlh-94-vuc">
                        <rect key="frame" x="79" y="344" width="40" height="30"/>
                        <state key="normal" title="Share"/>
                    </button>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="m0R-Do-Mr3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="60" width="398" height="61"/>
                        <string key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</string>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="aLg-Yr-ndG" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="8dT-Db-15Z"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="tub-UY-Qc6" secondAttribute="trailing" id="9MJ-uw-1Ca"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="tub-UY-Qc6" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="leading" id="AQ3-kJ-tVu"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="bBl-zC-cYt" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Ble-Sl-XKb"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Vlh-94-vuc" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="aLg-Yr-ndG" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="DR1-ea-Juj"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="FaY-ve-Qel" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="JO1-nS-Fg0" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Drr-Jg-bR2"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="JO1-nS-Fg0" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="OFG-JM-p5H"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="FaY-ve-Qel" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="4cS-dj-yG9" secondAttribute="bottom" id="RBR-GS-VdH"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="m0R-Do-Mr3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="JO1-nS-Fg0" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="Ty0-OF-WPY"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Vlh-94-vuc" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="tub-UY-Qc6" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="UEv-aP-CfW"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="bBl-zC-cYt" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="WtV-1Y-RiY"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="JO1-nS-Fg0" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="fBu-gb-Qqo"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="aLg-Yr-ndG" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="tub-UY-Qc6" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="kn4-84-3pp"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="m0R-Do-Mr3" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="qQ9-nk-akg"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="4cS-dj-yG9" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="JO1-nS-Fg0" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="tlM-VO-hmV"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="m0R-Do-Mr3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="ujA-dg-oXB"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="aLg-Yr-ndG" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="yGd-EI-YmC"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="4cS-dj-yG9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="hnF-dN-5dt" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="yyJ-Yv-nge"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="tub-UY-Qc6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="m0R-Do-Mr3" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="zrG-g2-2ab"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="source" destination="m0R-Do-Mr3" id="SnG-VN-51c"/>
                <outlet property="title" destination="4cS-dj-yG9" id="uHh-s1-WgP"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="124.6376811594203" y="96.428571428571431"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Results on an iPhone 11:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should return correct cell height for UITableViewCell to display properly.
There are 2 ways:

1. Fixed height: implement this function in UITableViewDelegate and return value

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//...
}
```

2. If you want your cell to expand its height based on its content. Try two functions below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//...
}
```

Comment: Even if i return 500 in the heightForRowAt I encounter this problem